# Lower background music volume when autoplay HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that has some animal images and when you click on them it plays the sound of the animal, but since its a kid's game I have a background music, but the sound is too loud. I want when  the background music plays automatically, the volume changes to 0.5. How can I set a function that does that? I don't want a function based on click, I want it hidden and change the volume automatically.

The function (it's not working)

```
myAudio = document.getElementById("audio1");

function setHalfVolume() { 
    myAudio.volume = 0.4;
}
```

HTML

```
<audio id= "audio1" controls="controls"  onload="setHalfVolume()">
    <source src="Audio\Jaunty Gumption.mp3"  type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Comment: Try initialize myAudio inside function

function setHalfVolume() { 
myAudio = document.getElementById("audio1"); 
    myAudio.volume = 0.4;
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event you need is called [onloadeddata](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#handler-mediacontroller-onloadeddata).

Also unless you need access to the myAudio variable from other functions or globally I would suggest moving it into the `setHalfVolume` function. Give this a try.

Change your HTML to:

```
<audio id= "audio1" controls="controls" onloadeddata="setHalfVolume()">
    <source src="Audio\Jaunty Gumption.mp3"  type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Change your JavaScript to:

```
function setHalfVolume() {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById("audio1");  
    myAudio.volume = 0.5; //Changed this to 0.5 or 50% volume since the function is called Set Half Volume ;)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an event for `play` on all of the audio elements of interest and calling setHalfVolume in there:

```
document.querySelector('#audio1').addEventListener('play', setHalfVolume);
```

You'll also probably want to reset the volume back to normal after

```
document.querySelector('#audio1').addEventListener('pause', resetVolume);
```

Where `resetVolume` and `setHalfVolume` are declared sort of like:

```
function setHalfVolume() { 
    document.getElementById("audio1").volume /= 2;
}
function resetVolume() { 
    document.getElementById("audio1").volume *= 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :), your answer did work for me as well, but I didn't wanted to implement jquery...its just my choice but I know its simpler than javascript solely.

Comment: @Marve there is no jQuery in megawac's answer

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry. You are right. Im sorry @megawac I saw an $ somewhere else then.

Comment: No worries, inline events are not considered too bad of a practice with media elements (to my knowledge) but I'd recommend you try to avoid inlining events whenever possible.